# Program hangs when trying to open a connection to ClickhouseDB?

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, ado.net, clickhouse

I am trying to connect to a local ClickhouseDB from my application to execute some raw queries. The problem arises when I try to open the connection. It never returns from the method call.

The ClickhouseDB is started within a docker container.

```cs
using (ClickHouseConnection conn = connFactory.CreateConnection(new ClickHouseConnectionSettings(connectionString)))
            {
                var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from default.table_name";

                conn.Open(); // it never goes past this line
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                ...
```

I'd like to open a connection after the `conn.Open()` and continue with the program on to the next line of executing the reader.

**NOTE:**
If I try to connect from a python console there are absolutely no problems.

```py
from clickhouse_driver import Client
client = Client(host='localhost')
client.execute('select * from default.table_name')
# [(4, 'four'), (5, 'five'), (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')]
```

**UPDATE:**
Stacktrace after ConnectionTimeout:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at InhouseNamespace.ClickHouse.Impl.ProtocolFormatter.ReadBytes(Int32 i)
   ...
```

docker-compose that deploys Clickhouse. I'm not a docker expert so I was satisfied with the DB when it got going and I was able to connect to it through Tabix web UI:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  clickhouse:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-server
    ports:
    - "8123:8123"
    - "9000:9000"
    - "9009:9009"

    ulimits:
     nproc: 65535
     nofile:
      soft: 262144
      hard: 262144
 client:
    image: yandex/clickhouse-client
    command: ['--host', 'server']
```

**UPDATE:**
After connecting to a non local CassandraDB, the problem disappeared, meaning there is a problem in connecting to my local CassandraDb (in the docker container).

Comment: If you wait long enough, you'll get an exception that should provide more information to the issue. Can you also provide what the connection string looks like?

Comment: `connString = "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=8123;User=default;Password=;Database=default;Compress=True;CheckCompressedHash=False;SocketTimeout=60000000;Compressor=lz4"`
I've just noticed socketTimeout, I'll decrease it and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, that timeout is insanely high.  Can you also post the docker config?  ie: What command you used to start the container?

Comment: I've posted the content of docker-compose. I simply called `docker-compose up`

Comment: Were you able to try updating the connection string to see if that was the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 8123 is used as a default port for the HTTP interface. But while using:

```
conn.Open();
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

the communication is done through the native clickhouse client and therefore port 9000 has to be used.

To fix the problem, change the port in your connection string. The complete connection string would then look like this: `connString = "Host=127.0.0.1;Port=9000;User=default;Password=;Database=default;Compress=True;CheckCompressedHash=False;SocketTimeout=60000000;Compressor=lz4"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the connection string that you are using is not correct.

Take out the "port" key and append the port number to the server (which you have named 'host' right now) key like so:

"Server=127.0.0.1,8123;User=default;Password=;Database=default;Compress=True;CheckCompressedHash=False;SocketTimeout=60000000;Compressor=lz4"

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: It give a 500 error. `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)`

Comment: Sorry, change the word "Host" to "Server"

Comment: @Marko Sorry, updated the solution (connection string Host-->Server)